# Multithreaded UDP server using ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hi am building a Peer2Peer network using UDP socket each time the server receives a message from the client it create a thread to deal with the request.am trying to implement a ThreadPool Queue to store the request and limit the number of thread running on the machine and whenever a thread is free we get threads from the queue (Producer/Consumer),i have been trying for a while now but the new threads don't get added on the queue i end executing only the first thread that was added.

```
 
    public void run() {
```

`BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue=new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

    ExecutorService tpes =Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    int server_port = 8767;
    DatagramSocket s = null;
    while(true){
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);

        try{
            s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
        }catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Socket excep");
        }

        try {
            s.receive(p);
            queue.put(new RequestHandler(p));
            tpes.execute(queue.take());

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IO EXcept");
        }
        finally{
            s.close();
        }
    }
}`

I don't know where am going wrong ? any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is that run method the one of `RequestHandler`? You create strange recursion. Also if you `.take()` the object you've just put there a few lines earlier you could just use it directly.

Comment: the run method is not of the RequestHandler it's a part of the peerNode that can act like a server in the run i listen to request and i create thread and the RequestHandler class takes care of the rest.
I don't want to use the object directly because i'll be creating to many threads (1 thread per request) i want to use a queue and store the threads and use a fixed number of threads.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `Queue` of your own. An `ExecutorService` has a queue for tasks. I would also suggest not to open a new socket each time since you can re-use them.

The resulting code might look roughly like this.

```
public void run() {
    ExecutorService tpes = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    int server_port = 8767;
    DatagramSocket s = null;
    try {
        s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
        while (true) {
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
            try {
                s.receive(p);
                tpes.execute(new RequestHandler(p));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Socket excep");
    } finally {
        if (s != null) s.close();
    }
}
```

The `RequestHandler` will run on one of 10 threads and if you get more requests than 10 threads can handle you will have a queue of pending `RequestHandler` tasks within the `Executor`.

Note: I don't think it makes sense to run `RequestHandler` on a thread pool. Handling 1kB of data is not much and e.g. writing that data to the harddrive is faster than you can recieve packets. (unless you are on fibre and your harddisk is terribly slow).

Comment: i followed your suggestions but it didn't solve the problem, the run method is using the same socket the method is part of a PeerNode class so whenever a node is instantiated it will listen to the same port.the requestHandler receives the packet and process it and send an answer back to the client based on the content of the packet and it's all running locally as it is just an exercise . the idea is to build a peer2peer search engine where each node is indexing a part of the web.

Comment: @Mero well udp is "connectionless" and there is no notion of a special connection when you recieve a packet. They are just plain packets to a port and you reply to the sender. Or not. There is nothing that is "connected" that you would have to "disconnect". No idea how to build such a P2P network.

Comment: each node has a Node_id and keep a list of other nodes ID's that's how and as long as you know the ID and the port and the IP (local host) in this case you can talk to a specific node in the network. that's the approach am taking

Comment: What you probably need to do is to keep a `Map<SenderId, RequestHandler>` where senderId is the address + port. Then you "route" every packet you recieve to the correct handler by looking it up in the map, creating it when necessary.

Comment: the issue i have is not with handling the packets. i just want to limit the number of threads running so each time i get a client request i put it in a queue if all the threads are busy and once a thread is free it will check the queue and handle the request.i thought the ExecutorService will help me to achieve that but there's something wrong with my implementation.by the way thank you for your suggestions